# bash regex: asterisk metacharacter kills redundant newline characters

Tags: regular-expression

To test the basic functioning of the asterisk metacharacter in search operations using `grep`, I used a file (`regex.txt`) with the following contents:

```
$ cat regex.txt
1
11
111
1111
11111





$
```

There are 6 newlines after the `11111` in my example, intentionally added.

### Question 1.

Why does the output of `grep "11*" regex.txt` not include the newlines after `11111` unlike the output of `grep "1*" regex.txt`?

### Question 2.

The output of `grep "111*" regex.txt` is

```
11
111
1111
11111
```

The output of `grep "1111*" regex.txt` is

```
111
1111
11111
```

The output of `grep "11111*" regex.txt` is

```
1111
11111
```

Why are the top layers missing for every increase in '1' in the search key?

Comment: Please read the help on [formatting tools](http://unix.stackexchange.com/help/formatting) to learn how to format your posts correctly.

Comment: Also, please take the time to read a basic regular expression primer as I asked before. You need to understand the basics before trying to use them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your two questions are basically the same. In regular expressions, `*` means "match the previous character 0 or more times". So, `1*` will match 0 or more `1` but `11*` will match a `1` *followed* by 0 or more `1`. This means that

- `grep "11*"` will only print lines containing *at least* one `1`. The `*` only applies to the second `1`, so the first is obligatory. That's why you don't see the empty lines, they don't match `1`.
- `grep "1*"` will match 0 or more `1`. Here, you don't have a preceding character that needs to be matched so the blank lines are also matched because they contain 0 `1`.
- `grep "111*"`, `grep "1111*"` etc don't match for the same reason as the first point above. `111*` will only print lines containing *at least* 2 `1`, possibly more. `1111*` will match lines containing *at least* 3 `1`, possibly more.

The main point here is that the `*` only affects the character immediately before it, not the entire pattern. To give a quantifier to an entire pattern you can use parentheses:

```
$ grep '\(111\)*' regex.txt 
1
11
111
1111
11111





$
```

Here, the parentheses (they need to be escaped with `\` so they won't be included in the search pattern) group the characters together so the `*` is applied to the group. As you see above, that matches lines containing 0 or more occurrences of `111`, so it prints all lines.

Comment: repeated sub-expressions select only the last successive occurrence of the match. probably not terribly important with `grep`, but could be interesting with GNU's `-o`, I guess.

Answer (score 0):

`'1*'` selects zero or more characters that are one. `1` selects one character that is one. A blank line doesn't have have any characters that are one, but it *does* have zero characters that are one.